# How revert to 12.10 from 13.04?

Tags: 12.10, 13.04

Is there a way to revert to 12.10 from 13.04?
Since I upgraded, my laptop behaves strangely, slowed down, freezes, the ventilator doen't work anymore and I get error messages like the following: [    16671286]usb 4-1 string descriptor 0 read error -22 | <@

Comment: Not easily, no. A clean install is usually the fastest way to a working install.